# Response в Servlet

Tags: java, servlet

Как вернуть в Response Java-обьект из Сервлета на представление(HTML-Page , принимаю в ajax)???

Comment: Что значит _Вернуть в Response_?

Comment: ок, запихнуть в респонз!

Comment: Вы хотите вывести на HTML страницу объект Java?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, кому нужно - вот на беке код! Что б передать обьект java на предаставление!

```
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(21);
    user.setName("John");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(user);
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(json);
```

А разобрать на представлении -

```
  $.ajax({
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/servletURL",
    'method': 'get',
    'success': function (response) {
       console.log(response);
       console.log(response.id);
       console.log(response.name);
    },
    'error': function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(error));
    }
  });
```

Comment: `resp.setContentType("application/json")` пользователь ничего не увидит, он может "увидеть" только `html` страницу. `json` или `xml` возвращают только веб сервисы.

Comment: @notaProgrammer Так автору этого вроде и не надо. Ответ обрабатывается javascript-ом. В примере вон просто в консоль выводит. Явно речь идёт об обновлении каких-то полей в представлении через ajax

Comment: Автору на заметку. Есть ещё в java restful webservice. Поддерживает json сразу же. Да и модно сейчас всё делать через rest. Servlet-ы сейчас базовый уровень. И многое делается через надстройки на ними для популярных технологий.

Comment: Знаю, в спринге вообще незаморачиваясь все делается. Но дали таск с сервлетами - должен сделать)Спасибо за ответы! П.С. Консоль - простой пример, что б не ломать еще голову куда вставляется ответ и т.д.